# Matlab -> variable name update inside a function

Tags: matlab, variables

Does anyone know how to update the name of variable "X" in a function?

For instance I have X[i] and I want to obtain X[i+1]. How do I firstly declare the initial variable and how do I update the name of it (in this case the index).

**Edit 1: Better explanation.**

I have some computation as output in the form of different size arrays. I want to name the matrix as depending on an index, for instance: array[i]=output(corresponding to the i index) array[j]=output(corresponding to the j index)

So, basically, I want to assign index dependent names to some variables but not manually.

Thanks!

Comment: The `index` in a vector/matrix and the `name` of a variable are 2 different things ... what exactly are you asking ?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Try to describe your goal, and put some code (or pseudo-code) to demonstrate it.

Comment: You never want to do this in Matlab. Never. Never. Never. Never. **Never**. Use a cell array.

Comment: I think I'll use a struct instead. Thanks!